# Displaying photo captured using 3rd party android application in my application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I'm having trouble showing the current image that I have captured using a 3rd party android application and showing it on my own native app. It's always an empty screen with just the action bar. However, the photo taken could be located in the folder i have specified.

Could someone kindly assist? Greatly appreciated! Cheers :)

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linear">

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Source Code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
    switch(requestCode) {
    case 0:
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    break; 

    case 1:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        }
    break;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where is the image store by 3rd party application?

Comment: Hi, I have specified it to be on the SD Card -> Pictures -> MyCreatedFolder

Comment: Then you can get the image file name from sdcard and place it in ImageView.
Thats so simple? where is the problem you are getting

Comment: Hi Amit, i was just wondering if i could get the code above to work. Its displaying a blank screen after i have captured an image.

Comment: so are you selecting photogallery and then placing the image??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
```

add above line to your xml of the ImageView where desc should be in string.xml and set it to something.
Looks like this defines text that briefly describes content of the view. This property is used primarily for accessibility. Since some views do not have textual representation this attribute can be used for providing such.

Non-textual widgets like ImageViews and ImageButtons should use the contentDescription attribute to specify a textual description of the widget such that screen readers and other accessibility tools can adequately describe the user interface.

```
String  selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

use the above code

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: Hi Amit. Thats not really what i wanted. What i wanted was to display the photo that i have just captured from the current intent. At the same time, im having this error for my imageview "[Accessibility] Missing contentDescription attribute on image". could you kindly assist. What im having now is a blank screen with just an action bar after the image has been captured. I want the photo in which i have just taken to be displayed via the image view. Thanks!!!

Comment: Hi Amit, I have edited my post and attached the full source code that i have.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saving the value of `fileUri` in your `Activity`? If so are you recovering it from saved instance?

If not it could possibly be reset when the activity is destroyed.